# Can I monitor a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I hope to monitor a variable, I will do sometings when the variable changed, maybe just like Code A.

How can I write these code in Kotlin? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
var myList: List<Int>

registerMonitorVar(myList)

fun onVariableChange(){
   if (myList.size>=1){
      btnDelete.enabled=true
   }
}
```

**To ice1000**

Thanks! but the following code doesn't work! I don't know how to init allList when I need set property.

```
private lateinit var allList: MutableList<MSetting> set(value) {
        field = value
        onVariableChange()
}

private  var allList=mutableListOf<MSetting>() set(value) {
        field = value
        onVariableChange()
}

fun onVariableChange(){
    if (allList.size>=1){

     }
}
```

**To humazed:**

Thanks! why isn't the following code correct?

```
 private var allList: MutableList<MSetting>  by Delegates.vetoable(mutableListOf<MSetting>())
    { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        {
            btnRestore.isEnabled=(newValue.size >= 1)
            btnBackup.isEnabled=(newValue.size >= 1)
        }

    }
```

**To humazed and ice1000**

Thanks! The system can't monitor the change of the var allList when I use  Code 2

```
 private var allList: MutableList<MSetting>  by Delegates.observable(mutableListOf<MSetting>())
    { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        btnRestore.isEnabled = newValue.size >= 1
    }
```

**Code 1**

```
allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting().toMutableList() // Observable Work
```

**Code 2**

```
allList.clear()
 allList.addAll(SettingHandler().getListAllSetting().toMutableList()) //Observable Doesn't Work
```

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin [observable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html) and [vetoable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/vetoable.html) is perfect for this use case.

vetoable is doing just what you want. from the doc:

> **vetoable**:
>    Returns a property delegate for a read/write property that
>   calls a specified callback function when changed, allowing the
>   callback to veto the modification.

for your example, you can use:

```
var myList: List<Int> by Delegates.vetoable(listOf()) { property, oldValue, newValue ->
    if (newValue.size >= 1)
        true // apply the change to myList
    else
        false // ignore the change. ie. myList stay the same.
}
```

or simply:

```
var myList: List<Int> by Delegates.vetoable(listOf()) { property, oldValue, newValue ->
    newValue.isNotEmpty()
}
```

---

**After your edit**. I see in your next example observable is more suitable as you seem to want the list to be changed regardless of any condition.

```
var allList: MutableList<String>  by Delegates.observable(mutableListOf<String>()) { property, oldValue, newValue ->
    btnRestore.isEnabled = newValue.size >= 1
    btnBackup.isEnabled = newValue.size >= 1
}
```

your code didn't work because you added unnecessary `{}` and used `vetoable` without returning neither true nor false.

---

---

For the edited answer. it deserves its own question but I'm going to answer it here anyway.

you could use `list` and when you want to change the list replace it with the new list. this has performance implications since you creating a new list every time you need to add or remove an item.

or you could extend the list class or use extension functions to react to add and delete operations. ex:-

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myList = mutableListOf<Int>()

    myList.addAllAndNotify(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4))
    myList.addAllAndNotify(listOf(1, 2, 88, 9))
}

fun <E> MutableList<E>.addAllAndNotify(elements: Collection<E>) {
    addAll(elements)
    doStuff(this)
}

fun <E> doStuff(list: List<E>) {
    println("list = ${list}")
}
```

the output:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 88, 9]
```

---

finally, you could take a look at this nice [lib](https://github.com/lightningkite/kotlin-observable) which has ObservableList if this what you need you better of using it instead of writing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks!, would you please see my modified question?

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer, but it's better if you ask a new question and posted the link here the next time.

Comment: Thank you very much, which one is more better between your code and ice1000's code ?

Comment: I think mine. as it gives you more flexibility and for me is more obvious what I'm trying to accomplish. they put it in kotlin stander library for a reason.

Comment: Thanks! If I use the code `allList.addAll(...)` to change the value of allList, your monitor code will not work!

Please see my modified question.

Comment: As it should, when you allList.addAll you are not changing the list you are modifying its content which will won't trigger the observable.  
after you call addAll call the method you want.  
and consider adding it to extension method addAllAndNotify for convenience.   

but observable is not the solution here.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me some sample code about "adding it to extension method addAllAndNotify for convenience"

Answer (score 3):

You can override the and setter.

```
var myList: List<Int> // maybe here's a missing initialization 
  set(value) {
    field = value
    onVariableChange()
  }

fun onVariableChange() {
   if (myList.size >= 1) {
      btnDelete.enabled = true
   }
}
```

By this, if you do `myList = blabla`, `onVariableChange` will be called.

To the edit, why doesn't

```
private var allList = mutableListOf<String>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        onVariableChange()
    }


fun onVariableChange() {
    if (allList.size >= 1) {
    }
}
```

This code work?

To the comment, you may use this:

```
private var allList = listOf<String>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        onVariableChange()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!, would you please see my modified question?

Comment: Thanks! If I use the code `allList.addAll(...) `to change the value of allList, your monitor code will not work!

Please see my modified question.

Comment: You may make this list immutable, and people can only "set" your list. Than you can monitor all the changes.

Comment: Thanks! How can I make this list immutable, and people can only "set" my list,could you show me some sample code?

Comment: Use `List` instead of `MutableList` or `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. See my edit